# Conda command not recognized in docker

Tags: python, docker, conda

My docker file is build using

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-bullseye

RUN cd $HOME
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt -y install bzip2 curl gpg
RUN curl https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/gpgkeys/anaconda.asc | gpg --dearmor > conda.gpg
RUN install -o root -g root -m 644 conda.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN gpg --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg --no-default-keyring --fingerprint 34161F5BF5EB1D4BFBBB8F0A8AEB4F8B29D82806
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/debrepo/conda stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/conda.list
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install conda
RUN . /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
RUN apt-get clean
CMD ["bash"]
```

I m building it using:

```
docker build \
    -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:latest \
```

I m pushing it :

```
docker push ${IMAGE_NAME}:latest
```

I m pulling this image:

```
 docker pull docker.company.com/image
```

I try running it

```
docker run -i -t docker.company.com/image
```

But this keep failing:

```
root@11111:/# conda update conda
```

Error - bash: conda: command not found

Expected behaviour- No error should come.

During my build i m installing conda. What am I missing. Can someone help.

Comment: An executable named `conda` is not in the current $PATH. obviously.  This shouldn't be a problem that has anything to do with Docker.   I assume it's just a matter of correctly setting up the environment.  I would suggest that once you're at the command prompt in the container, you look around and figure what actually got installed and why `conda` isn't in the PATH.  This isn't about programming, so this really isn't a question that is in scope for Stack Overflow.   You would be better off posting on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or one of the Linux-specific SE sites.

Comment: Most things in Docker don't read shell dotfiles at all, and environment variable settings don't last beyond the current `RUN` command; `RUN . conda.sh` doesn't actually do anything.  You need to set `ENV PATH=...` to point at the Conda installation; the linked question has further details.